# ffmpeg error using Fade Seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to fade a video clip in and out with a duration of a few seconds, and ffmpeg seemed like the best way.
The documentation mentions a [fade option](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade), and I have it working with a time in frames, but I really want to be able to use seconds.

Using the example from the docs, and adding the following to a working encode command:

```
-vf "fade=t=in:st=5.5:d=0.5"
```

I get:

```
[fade @ 0x102f009a0] Option 'st' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x102f00d00] Error initializing filter 'fade' with args 't=in:st=5.5:d=0.5'
```

I get the same error using the long argument `start_time`

I have ffmpeg version 1.2 and libavfilter `3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103`

I would use frames to specify the fade time and duration, but I'm specifying clip length in seconds, and I have no idea how long the clip will be in frames. To specify fade out I need to know the length in frames, and then specify the start time as `num_frames - fade_duration_in_frames`.

Has anyone else hit this problem?

Comment: It is working for me. But I have Libavfilter version `3. 60.101 /  3. 60.101` which I retrieved from Git at 25th april. I think that is your problem, probably your old libavfilter version can't handle that option yet?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version from Git, rather than the static OSX build and the version on Brew. That was the problem. It seems Libavfilter isn't updated as much on there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old version of Libavfilter where those filters are not yet implemented. I've tested it with a recent libavfilter version `3. 60.101 / 3. 60.101` and it is working correctly. Try building FFmpeg again using the current version and it should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the `libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100` and got the same problem with `st` and `start_time`.

The actual problem might not be `st` or `start_time`. Check logs I got few other commands related problems in `filter_complex`.
On checking the log and fixing it I didn't get any `st` and `start_time` related issue